# Update label with new NSDate

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsdate, nstimer

I have a the today date in a NSDate and I want to display this NSDate in a label. I want to change the label text with the new NSDate every time the seconds changes. I tried to use a NSTimer but it isn't synchronized with the iPhone clock. Is there any specific thing to directly have the label changed?

Comment: This is straigt forward question even answer would be. But if you show your code, we may figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a property timer as :

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(showTime)
                                       userInfo:NULL
                                        repeats:YES];
```

And then this method will be called every half of a second.

```
- (void)showTime{
    NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    timeLabel.text=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
}
```